# Уместно ли в приведённом контексте "по иронии судьбы"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> «Цеппелин» обожаю. По иронии судьбы я встречаю там таких людей,
>   которых я больше всего на свете хотела бы встретить. И уже не верила,
>   что встречу. Это просто счастье.

Разве ирония судьбы не имеет негативных коннотаций?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка**:
ИРОНИЯ СУДЬБЫ
*Экспрес.* Нелепая случайность.
*Синонимы*: дело случая, игра случая, игра судьбы, случай, случайность, стечение обстоятельств.

[**Большой словарь русских поговорок**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/24254/%D0%98%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)
**Ирония судьбы**
1. *Книжн.* Нелепая случайность (с неприятными, иногда трагическими последствиями).
2. *Шутл.* **Удивительный, совершенно непредвиденный поворот судьбы.**

**Толковый словарь русского языка под редакцией Д. Н. Ушакова:**
ИРОНИЯ СУДЬБЫ (*книжн.*) — насмешка судьбы, **странная, непонятная случайность.**

"Ирония судьбы", конечно, чаще имеет отрицательный подтекст, но есть и позитивные примеры: везение, удивление, удовольствие или улыбка:

*...редакторская должность, которую я по чистому недоразумению занимала в газете «Молодой ленинец», – это была ирония судьбы. Бывает же так – шутит над нами судьба, и надо мной она подшутила, сделав меня редактором.*
А. Щербаков. Шелопут и Королева

*По иронии судьбы мне почему-то попадаются мужчины с птичьими фамилиями.*
Е. Алексеева-Орлова. Птицы счастья

*Мужчина замерз бы в снегах, но его, по иронии судьбы, заметил Таусон. Человек, за которым капитан охотился более шести лет. (...) Только благодаря ему Сэмюэл выжил.*
А. Афанасьева. Железная птица алого цвета

Думаю, что "по иронии судьбы" в этом тексте можно использовать.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что нет: после первой части предложения ожидается концовка "**меньше** всего хотела бы встретить". Создаётся впечатление, что автор живёт с ощущением "чем хуже, тем лучше", а жизнь расставляет ловушки и делает хорошо (далее автор опровергает это предположение, да и в самом начале от посещения кабака явно ждёт удачи).

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, "по иронии судьбы" здесь употреблено неверно. Может быть оправдано, если показано, в чем ирония судьбы (добрая или злая). Например, так:

**Там по иронии судьбы я встречаю таких людей, каких уже не верила что встречу. Хотя больше всего на свете хотела бы встретить. Это просто счастье.**

Не верила, что встречу — и встретила. Это ирония судьбы.
И еще. В моем варианте *там* стоит в стороне от *иронии судьбы*. В противном случае нет ответа на вопрос, как проявилась ирония судьбы в том, что именно **там**.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А вот за *которых уже не верила что встречу* с запятой вовнутрях вообще-то канделябром...

Comment: Да, пожалуй, вернее сказать "тех людей, которых..." или "таких людей, каких...". А поправлю ответ. Но это проблема есть и в исходном тексте.

Answer (score 1):

Да, выражение "по иронии судьбы" здесь не у места. **Ирония – это насмешка, а нет насмешки – нет и иронии.**

Как вариант: «Цеппелин» обожаю. **Удивительно,** но я встречаю там таких людей, которых я больше всего на свете хотела бы встретить. И уже не верила, что встречу. Это просто счастье.

ИРОНИЯ, 1. Тонкая, скрытая насмешка.  И. судьбы (**нелепая, странная случайность**). По иронии судьбы он оказался там, куда и не собирался. По злой иронии (как будто в насмешку). Не хотел после института возвращаться в родной город, но по злой иронии именно туда и попал работать.

Comment: Жасминчик, я согласна, именно это меня и споткнуло, но Римма привела убедительные примеры из худлитры, и я решила не дёргать автора по сомнительным и имеющим толкование в его пользу случаям.